# Select a cell from the table and giving it unique class

Tags: javascript, html, css, excel, es6-class

I have 49 cells (7x7 rows/cols), and I'm trying to create one cell out of the 49 cells to be unique, as you can see when you run the snippet, the 49 cells have random numbers between 50 to 500, and one of these cells have Red color.

The problem I'm struggling with, I want that one cell to have Symbol (marking plate) like S or D for example instead of number, How i can achieve that?

```js
var isCol = 0;
var board = [];
for (r = 0; r < 7; r++) {
  var line = [];
  for (c = 0; c < 7; c++) {
    line.push(RandomGenerator(50, 500));
  }
  board.push(line);
}

function prs(c, r) {
  showTable(c, r);
  isCol = (isCol + 1) % 2;
}

function toColor(col, row, chosen_col, chosen_row) {
  var ret = false;
  switch (isCol) {
    case 0:
      if (row == chosen_row) {
        ret = true;
      }
      break;
    case 1:
      if (col == chosen_col) {
        ret = true;
      }
      break;
  }

  return ret;
}

function showTable(chosen_col, chosen_row) {
  var str = "";
  str += "<table border=1>";
  for (row = 0; row < 7; row++) {
    str += "<tr>";
    for (col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
      str += "<td onclick='prs(" + col + "," + row + ")'";
      if (toColor(col, row, chosen_col, chosen_row)) {
        str += " class='grn' ";
      }
      str += ">";
      str += board[row][col];
      str += "</td>";
    }
    str += "</tr>";
  }
  str += "</table>";

  document.getElementById("ff").innerHTML = str;
}

function RandomGenerator(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

showTable(-1);

var getUnique = function(){
  var tdElements = document.querySelectorAll('#ff td');
  tdElements[
    RandomGenerator(0, tdElements.length)
  ].classList.add('uniqueCell')
};
getUnique();
```

```css
td{
border:2px solid black;
width:10px;
height:10px;
}
td:hover{background-color:lightgreen;}
.grn{
background-color:green;
color:white;
}

.uniqueCell {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div id="ff"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems pretty easy as you have a class (*uniqueCell*) in the element. You can simply target the cell with the class (*uniqueCell*) and set the *innerText* or *textContent* property:

```
document.querySelector('.uniqueCell').textContent = 'S';
```

```js
var isCol = 0;
var board = [];
for (r = 0; r < 7; r++) {
  var line = [];
  for (c = 0; c < 7; c++) {
    line.push(RandomGenerator(50, 500));
  }
  board.push(line);
}

function prs(curr, c, r) {
  showTable(curr, c, r);
  isCol = (isCol + 1) % 2;
}

function toColor(col, row, chosen_col, chosen_row) {
  var ret = false;
  switch (isCol) {
    case 0:
      if (row == chosen_row) {
        ret = true;
      }
      break;
    case 1:
      if (col == chosen_col) {
        ret = true;
      }
      break;
  }
  return ret;
}

function showTable(c, chosen_col, chosen_row) {
  var str = "";
  str += "<table border=1>";
  for (row = 0; row < 7; row++) {
    str += "<tr>";
    for (let col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
      str += "<td onclick='prs(this, " + col + "," + row + ")'";
      if (toColor(col, row, chosen_col, chosen_row)) {
        if(c.textContent == board[row][col]){
          str += " class=uniqueCell";
        }
        else str += " class='grn' ";
      }
      str += ">";
      if(c.textContent == board[row][col]){
        str += 'S';
      }
      else str += board[row][col];
      str += "</td>";
    }
    str += "</tr>";
  }
  str += "</table>";

  document.getElementById("ff").innerHTML = str;
}

function RandomGenerator(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

showTable(-1);

var getUnique = function(){
  var tdElements = document.querySelectorAll('#ff td');
  tdElements[
    RandomGenerator(0, tdElements.length)
  ].classList.add('uniqueCell');
  // update the text of the cell using the class
  document.querySelector('.uniqueCell').textContent = 'S';
};
getUnique();
```

```css
td{
  border:2px solid black;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  text-align: center;
}
td:hover{background-color:lightgreen;}
.grn{
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
}

.uniqueCell {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div id="ff"></div>
```

Comment: what the, I tried that and got error, but your code seems to work, do you think its also possible to let the unique cell stay in one cell and move it to other cells at will (by clicking on other cells)

Comment: @mikotodread, I don't know why you are getting error, I have simply added a single line of code in your code!!!

Comment: @mikotodread, do you want the unique cells *color* and *text* to remain when clicking other cells?

Comment: yeah, the main goal after all, to let player A pick vertical and player B to pick horizontal

Comment: @mikotodread, so you want the cell with class `uniqueCell` to be unselected when clicking cells?

Comment: For example, lets say uniqueCell = Cell01,  I click on Cell05,  unqiueCell moves to Cell05   (edit unique Cell = S too)

Comment: Cell05 loses its numbers, and gets "S" which is uniqueCell symbol, Cell01 stays empty, now I go from Cell05 to Cell032, Cell05 loses S and stays empty like Cell01, Cell032 loses its number and gets S symbol

Comment: @mikotodread, though I am not entirely clear about your requirement I have updated the code, please check:)

Comment: you're legend <3, there's only little problem  First Picture (https://prnt.sc/r7chbg)  Second Picture (https://prnt.sc/r7chpu)  third picture (https://prnt.sc/r7ci0f), as you can see the numbers not getting deleted after i place the symbol (to clarify: there was 201, I click on it, symbol replace it, which is working, good, then when i click other number, lets say 450, Symbol go to 450 and replace it, which is good, means its working however when i moved to 450, i want the 201 to not come back after i leave it, for it to stay empty